# How to use the generic class type parameter class

Tags: java, json, generics, jsonparser

I have a genetic class parameter

```
public static <T> T parse(String json, Class<T> clazz) {
   T result = null;
   result = mapper.readValue(json, clazz);

   return result;
}
```

Let say I have a json

```
{
    "name": "kim"
}
```

How should I create the POJO for `Class<T> clazz`?

```
public class Person<T>
{
    private T name;

    public T getName ()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName (T name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }


}
```

and how to pass the variable?

```
Person person = new Person();

parse(json, person) // ????
```

Comment: You probably mean _generic_ instead of _genetic_.

Comment: If an answer correctly answers your question please accept it. I see that you've asked ~30 questions and accepted an answer to only 1. Accepting answers is important for the site, you also get 2 rep points for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You can try starting from here. Rest should flow based on your requirements.

```
public class Person<T>
{
    private T name;
    public T getName (){
        return name;
    }

    public void setName (T name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
       Person<String> p = new Person<String>();
       p.setName("Some Name");
       System.out.println(p.getName());
    }

}
```

See this page: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Comment: if I create class as Person <br/> Person p  = new Person() <br/> and parse(json, p)?? <br/> but this gives error

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here but you can substitute T with any class you want. You can try something like Person<String> p = new Person<String>();. Please read the above mentioned document, it includes creating, instantiating and other examples as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON suggests that the `name` property of your object is a `String`. Therefore your object would look like

```
class Person {
    String name;
    // getter and setter
}
```

In this case there is no reason to have the POJO generic. Your last code block also suggests that this is the case. You would want to have `name` a generic type only if there can be different representations for it. Think of how `List<T>` uses its generic type. Would you want to have `Person<String>`, `Person<StringBuilder>`, `Person<MyObject>` all specifying different types of `name`? Probably not.

The generic usage does come to play in your `parse` method. `parse` takes a JSON `String` and a `Class` type in order to tell the mapper which Java class to create from the string:

```
public static <T> T parse(String json, Class<T> clazz)
```

That is, you take a `Class` of type `T` and return an *instance* of `T`. The usage would be (instead of your last code block):

```
Person person = parse(json, Person.class);
```

where `Person.class` is `Class<Person>`, which means that the method returns as `Person`.